# Launch error: could not create the Java virtual machine. A fatal exception has occurred

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10, 64-bit

Below is my Eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe
```

I did add the path for javaw.exe looking at some posts. But this addition just gave me a new error

1. How to fix this in my computer?
2. If someone can explain me on this launch config stuff in Eclipse?

Comment: You are using a 32bit VM, and 64bit eclipse, It won't work. You should either install a 64bit jvm or a 32bit eclipse.

Comment: `-vm` must be on a separate line from the javaw path, and they must come **before** the -vmargs line. It looks like you may have a 32 bit Java and a 64 bit Eclipse. They must both be 64 bit or both be 32 bit.

Comment: Thank you for your info!
This works now

Comment: Side note: had the same problem but in my case I had duplicted -vm at the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your JDK to 8u171 or higher.
I had the same issue with eclipse oxygen. This is worked for me.

Here's the URL for downloading the latest Java 8 JDK:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
If that should stop working, go to http://java.oracle.com and click "Java SE" under top downloads.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave removed my comment. Could not pick an appropriate comment. Should have formulate one myself. The problem is that the link is not valid. I get "unauthorized request". It is best to link to the download page itself with an accurate description which to pick instead of a link to file to be downloaded because that depends on either the current user/tracking cookie/file host.

Answer (score 0):

try to use java 8, it solve my problem when i degraded my jdk from 15 to 8, here is the link

[JAVA](https://enos.itcollege.ee/%7Ejpoial/allalaadimised/jdk8/)